# Remove mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a height and `overflow-x: hidden` so I can see the vertical scroll-bar.
Now when I scroll the whole page with the mouse wheel, if my cursor goes on the top of that div it starts scrolling the div instead of the page. Is it possible to remove mouse scrolling on this particular div?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how important is the content in that div but another solution could be to make your pointer have no effect on div `pointer-events:none`. More explanations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events).

Comment: this is exactly what i meant

Comment: does this stop mouse clicks such as links too?

Comment: This would stop mouse clicks on children; not the best.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think you can achieve something similar to this is by capturing the mouseover event of that particular div and disable the wheel for the whole page, and enable it again on mouseout. In this post you can see how to disable the wheel for the whole page : [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Answer (score 0):

No, because the user expects to be able to scroll a scrollable region with the mousewheel, and the user selects a scrollable region by moving the mouse pointer over it.

You can disable scrolling by setting `overflow-y: hidden` but that will cause the scrollbars to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can add a handler to the

```
onmousewheel
```

event to prevent it from scrolling (this is listed as HTML5 so might not work in older browsers). There's a full list of events here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp